# Connect Local Access Database to live website

Tags: php, ms-access

I have Access Database in my computer. I want to access that database from hosting server where my website is uploaded. Is it possible to do that? I am using php.

Comment: definitely not to be recommended - but possible.

Comment: This is too broad, as written: there are likely lots of ways to access files on your local computer (whether Access database or otherwise), and likely involve network connectivity / firewall / vpn types of solutions. Not sure how php comes into play, other than just opening a file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's important to put some effort into finding an existing solution to your issue online **before** posting a question.  For example, by copy the exact title of your question into Google, I found a lot of information, including: [Microsoft : **How to build an Access database to share on the Web (with video)**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/build-an-access-database-to-share-on-the-web-cca08e35-8e51-45ce-9269-8942b0deab26).  Also, please see [help/on-topic] as well as [ask] and also [mcve] .  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you web hosting allows external ODBC connections, then you can most certainly do this. However, less and less web sites allow external ODBC connections to the wild internet. (Too much hacking and risk). So while the web software can freely read + use data say in SQL server or MySQL, external sources such as access to connect to that database is possible, but often not allowed. (So you have to check with your web host is this is possible).

If external ODBC connections are not supported, then you have to build a process such as exporting the Access data as XML or a csv file. You then FTP (upload) the file, and then setup some software (code) on the web site that will open + process that file into the database.

For sure the easiest is a simple ODBC connection to the web hosting, but as noted, I see less and less web hosting plans that offer this ability due to security issues.

Note that a odbc connection if allowed simply means that you continue to run the access application on your desktop, but the data is on the web site and thus only one copy of the active data exists to be maintained.